# When an object is in free fall from rest at an infinite radius, is its potential energy proportional to its clock rate?

Tags: general-relativity, energy, gravity, potential-energy, free-fall

The total energy $E$ of an object in free fall from rest at an infinite radius is known to be

$$
E = m c^2
$$

As the object falls, its energy doesn't change since the object is merely moving freely through curved spacetime.

For a distant observer, is $E$ the sum of the potential energy $U$ and the kinetic energy $E_k$ such that

$$
U = \left(1 - \frac{r_0}{r}\right) mc^2
$$

and

$$
E_k = \left(\frac{r_0}{r}\right) m c^2
$$

?

Comment: From the source: Saying that the universe undergoes energy inflation and that something that looks redshifted actually has constant energy is a more complicated and convoluted way of looking at things. Why are photons that aren't near a massive source of gravitation also redshifted since their energy doesn't change but our global energy scale does?

Comment: As measured by whom?

Comment: Yes, the energy doesn't change. If you drop a 1kg brick into a black hole, the black hole mass increases by 1kg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume that the energy is measured by a stationary observer ($dr=0$).

Taking the spherically symmetric Schwarzschild metric as an example and radial infall from infinity at rest, then we know that.
$$\left(1 - \frac{r_s}{r}\right) \frac{dt}{d\tau} = 1$$
So this expression gives the time dilation inferred by an observer at infinity for an infalling object, which I assume is what you mean by the clock rate - the proper time interval  divided by the coordinate time interval.
$$ d\tau = dt (1-r_s/r)$$

This leads to expressions for $dr/dt$, a velocity in coordinate space time
$$\frac{dr}{dt}=-\left(1 - \frac{r}{r_s}\right)\left(\frac{r_s}{r}\right)^{1/2}$$
and a velocity according to a stationary observer at $r$
$$v = -\left(\frac{r_s}{r}\right)^{1/2}$$
Where, in each case, $r_s$ is the Schwarzschild radius and $c=1$ units are used.

The kinetic energy measured by the stationary observer is $(\gamma -1)mc^2$ and thus
$$ E_K = \left(\frac{1}{(1 - r_s/r)^{1/2}} -1\right)mc^2 $$

According to coordinate space time, the equivalent kinetic energy expression would be
$$E_K = \left(\frac{1}{[1 - (1   - r_s/r)^2 (r_s/r)]^{1/2}}-1\right ) mc^2$$
which also doesn't simplify to what you suggest, since you see that this approaches zero at the Schwarzschild radius.

I think that in GR, this simple separation between potential and kinetic energy is not possible.

Comment: IMHO it's possible Rob. But it isn't what you find in your textbook. See the 2013 AMPS paper [an apologia for firewalls](https://arxiv.org/abs/1304.6483). Tucked away in the conclusion on page 27 is footnote 31, containing a reference 87 to Friedwardt Winterberg’s 2001 paper [gamma ray bursters and Lorentzian relativity](https://www.degruyter.com/downloadpdf/j/zna.2001.56.issue-12/zna-2001-1216/zna-2001-1216.pdf). The point to note is that falling bodies _do not slow down_.